# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Whether it is possible to adjust mailing which will be automatically formed in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services until it turns out to send the report?

Comment: What exatcly are you trying to achieve? You want that Reporting Serverices automatically generated and sent reports to specific email?

Comment: I want that the message was resent until it goes